# Using biochemical standard state versus chemical standard state

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, reduction-potential

Can I use the table below to calculate the standard cell potential, $E^{\circ}$, of ethanol oxidation to acetaldehyde (EtOH + 1/2O2 $\rightarrow$ Acetaldehyde + H2O)? Does it matter that the half-reactions provided are in the biochemical standard state (ie at pH 7)? I'm asking because the H+ terms in the half-reactions cancel out, and H+ isn't in the net reaction.

[image]

Comment: (x + 0.421) - (y + 0.421) = x - y